# How can I disable the RELOAD button on Chrome or some others Browser by Javascript?

Tags: javascript, browser, reload

How can I disable the RELOAD button on Chrome or some others Browser by Javascript?

Comment: you can't - web pages have no access to the browsers so called chrome - (*nothing to do with Chrome, even though Chrome does have chrome*)

Comment: If it were possible, many people would likely stop using the browser that permitted it.

Comment: For some sensitive pages this functionality can be use do not know why downvote.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, In earlier versions of Google Chrome this was disabled by below JS:

```
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
      //this code disables F5/Ctrl+F5/Ctrl+R in Chrome, Firefox and Explorer
      document.onkeydown = disableF5
      function disableF5(e) { if ((e.which || e.keyCode) == 116 || ((e.which || e.keyCode) == 82 && e.ctrlKey)) e.preventDefault(); };
      $(document).on("keydown", disableF5);
  </script>
```